Pulling percentages of each land use type from individual buffer zones on QGIS
In QGIS 3.30 I have a map of ponds and am looking to find the surrounding land use of each pond within 100 metres. I have created buffer zones around each pond and have a land use map of the area.
I feel like there must be a way to automate it so I can end up with a list of buffer zones and the percentage of each land use type for each buffer zone but I'm not sure how to do it.

Is the "land use map" a raster map, or vector data?

It's a raster map

Does the raster map contain values, or is it a RGB-representation of the land uses?

I think it might be RGB. Its the 2023 land use map from UKCEH  https://catalogue.ceh.ac.uk/documents/73ecb85e-c55a-4505-9c39-526b464e1efd

If it is RGB for visualisation purposes, an automated analysis is rather challenging. My best bet would be either trying to vectorize the data, or to recreate the polygons of the raster map as vector data manually.

You can begin by running an intersection with land use as the input layer and buffer zones as the overlay layer
Secondly, calculate the area of the new intersection layer features then join the attribute table back to the old buffer layer
Finally calculate the percentages you need in the buffer layer
